# How to add Hubspot Form to Gatsbyjs website?

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to add the hubspot form to my gatsbyjs website. They have given below embed code but I wonder how to add the same to the gatsbyjs?

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/shell.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    region: "na1",
    portalId: "21773256",
    formId: "b01e1fed-a1f4-4683-bf86-8b4c6ee1ea67"
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have not tried anything since I don't how to do it.

Comment: Without more implementation details, project structure, trials it's difficult to say how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Use React Helmet and add your `Hubspotcode` on top like this

```
<Helmet>
   <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/shell.js"></script>
</Helmet>
```

And then use React `componentDidMount()` and initialize the code. Add a target attribute to your form so that it will render in that space

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.initializeHubspotForm();
}
initializeHubspotForm() {
    if ('hbspt' in window) {
        window.hbspt.forms.create({
        region: "na1",
        portalId: "21773256",
        formId: "b01e1fed-a1f4-4683-bf86-8b4c6ee1ea67",
        target: "#formContainer"
      });
    } else {
      setTimeout(this.initializeHubspotForm, 500)
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the form yourself, you can use https://github.com/jamaljeantobias/gatsby-source-hubspot-forms to get the form elements.

https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/v2/get_forms has the provided fields

https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form describes how to submit the form to hubspot